# How I added lineBreak in nodejs while making json data?

Tags: reactjs

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Saimon Sikder",
        "description": "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, unde eaque. A assumenda officia dolorum voluptas saepe laboriosam expedita, obcaecati rerum vero mollitia repellat tempore et esse praesentium impedit accusamus cumque quisquam ea? Pariatur, id laboriosam! Suscipit omnis corporis molestiae facere vero soluta tempore atque voluptatibus qui repudiandae nobis autem dolore saepe, magni in quibusdam ex neque voluptates voluptate vel? Voluptatibus est, quaerat rerum dolore, maiores vitae eius aliquam sunt quae magnam itaque? Architecto corrupti totam id nobis nulla consequuntur dolore voluptatum voluptatibus adipisci cumque minima modi, quas eaque eos, repellat itaque velit optio laborum, accusamus illo. Voluptatem, obcaecati enim!"
    }
]
```

I want to use linebreak or give para in description , How I do this without any error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: The line feed character (begin a new line) is `\n`.